# How to make child see parent variable change

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with passing data to child.
Excatly in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/G1EgZ6kQh9rMk3MMtRwA?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input #x />

    <br />
    <child [value]="variable"></child>

    <button (click)='test(x.value)'>Button</button>
  `,
  directives: [ ChildComponent ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public variable;


  test (x:any){
    console.log('test',x);
    this.variable = x;
  }

}
```

that is my main component when i change variable.

I assign a input value to variable and this variable is passed throught input to child and child should get new value of variable.
but it doesnt happen.
Does anybody knows where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to pass the value of the `<input>` not the `<input>` element itself.

```
<child [value]="x.value"></child>
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cc7nylgPbZMWzHtgJBiA?p=preview)

Comment: I changed my plunker. I meant when function change private or local variable in parent component why child component doesnt get changed value ?

Comment: I think it does. Why do you think it does not? What exact steps do I need to take to reproduce the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I cant show code because its from my job.
So i have an array in main component and i pass this array to child. When i initialize it the seetter on this variable logs me the change. 
after that when i push a object to array child setter doesnt logs me a change

Comment: Sorry, don't know how I should help if you can't provide the code. Your comment doesn't provide any information worth mentioning.

Comment: I edit a comment above because i hit enter and i think it will be a break line not a submit

Answer (score 0):

Your plunker code seems to work fine. I was able to see results just by modifying your @input property to just this:

`@Input() value;`